# Проблема с webpack и babel?

Tags: webpack, babel

По [данной инструкции](https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/beginning-with-webpack-4) установил и настроил webpack:

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "webpack.loc",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "server": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development --config=webpack.dev.config.js",
        "dev": "webpack --mode=development --config=webpack.dev.config.js",
        "prod": "webpack --mode=production --config=webpack.prod.config.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "webpack": "^4.20.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
    }
}
```

**webpack.dev.config.js**

```
const PATH = require('path');

const PATHS = {
    src: PATH.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/js/index.js'),
    prod: PATH.resolve(__dirname, 'prod')
};

const config = {};

config.entry = PATHS.src;

config.output = {
    path: PATHS.prod,
    filename: 'assets/js/output.bundle.js'
};

config.module = {
    rules: [

        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            ]
        },

    ]
};

config.devServer = {
    contentBase: PATHS.prod,
    port: 9000,
    compress: true,
    open: true
};

module.exports = config;
```

Далее в консоли выполняю `npm run dev` и получаю ошибку следующего плана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понимаю, то скрипт просит babel версии 7? Как тогда babel 7 поставить в моем случае?

---

**UPD 1:**

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "webpack.loc",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "server": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development --config=webpack.dev.config.js",
        "dev": "webpack --mode=development --config=webpack.dev.config.js",
        "prod": "webpack --mode=production --config=webpack.prod.config.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
        "webpack": "^4.20.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
    }
}
```

Удалил `node_modules` и заново все установил, в итоге получил другую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, будет достаточно вместо тамошней команды установки написать `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env babel-loader` (предварительно удалив стаый Babel, разумеется)

Comment: поставил, вылетела ошибка следующего характера: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-env' from 'C:\SERVER\domains\webpack.loc'
- Did you mean "@babel/env"?

Comment: И старый babel-loader тоже удалите. Если всё сломали и не удаляется, то переустановите node_modules с нуля что ли

Comment: Обновил вопрос...

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `presets: ['env']` написать `presets: ['@babel/preset-env']`

Comment: ошибка осталась так же

Comment: Ну а теперь я вам просто не верю. Я взял ваши конфиги, применил правки из своих комментариев, создал `src/assets/js/index.js` и набрал `npm install` и `npm run dev` — всё прекрасно собралось без ошибок

Comment: Создал отдельный проект, в нем заново все сделал так, как и Вы - та же ошибка, что и была ранее... Можете выложить архив со своим проектом чтобы я его мог скачать?Возможно я что то делаю не так...

Comment: Архив [тык](https://home.andreymal.org/webpack_test.7z), видео с его созданием [тык](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_nf3RvzxfU)

Comment: Если у вас даже с этим архивом ничего не будет, то вероятно у вас что-то где-то сломано у другом месте — например, установлены какие-нибудь глобальные модули или просто винда напрочь переломанная (у меня-то не винда вообще, хех)

Comment: Тоже не заработало, все та же ошибка... Проверил на ноуте - работает. Значит проблема в компе... Пишите как ответ, выберу Вас решением! Большое спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Ну это всё же не решение. Не исключено, что я не знаю чего-нибудь вендоспецифичного, а кто-нибудь знает и полный ответ напишет